# Facebook username not displaying in Angularjs app (using Firebase)

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am attempting to learn both Angular and Firebase but I am running into a problem when I try to display username, profile pic, etc that is returned from Facebook. I can log the object returned from FB to the console and see that it is indeed returning all of the appropriate info, but if I try to display any of the info in my view it does not work so not sure what step I am missing. I have included all necessary scripts so i don't think that is the problem Any advice is greatly appreciated. Also just let me know if I have left out any info that might help to find a solution.

My controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.login', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://shining-heat-2026.firebaseio.com");
    $scope.login = function () {
        ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function (error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
            } else {
                var myname = authData.facebook.displayName;
                var userName;
                console.log("hi" + " " + myname);
                console.log(authData);
            }
        });
        $scope.userName = authData.facebook.displayName;
    }
});
```

and view:

```
<div class="row myrow" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <button id="fblogin" type="button" ng-click="login()">FB Login</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">{{"Hi" + " " + userName}}</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">Right Login</div>
</div>
```

I have included all of the necessary scripts and bootstrapped the app in my index.html file so I don't that is an issue. Also if I set $scope.username to a string it will display in my view once I fire the login function.

Comment: Put assignment to scope variable ` $scope.userName = authData.facebook.displayName;` into the same section where proper name is logged to console. Actually with such code you should see errors in browser console: `'authData' is undefined`

Comment: Yes exactly, that is the precise error I am seeing. I have actually tried to place that line of code ($scope.userName = authData.facebook.displayName) in various places just to make sure that that was not the issue, but to no avail as of yet.

Comment: try using a $timeout, e.g 
```$timeout(function() {
      $scope.userName = authData.facebook.displayName;
  }
```
Make sure to inject $timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, way of programming which implies placing lines of code in random places until it starts working provides a lot of fun... However, to stop this game you need to know the correct combination.

`ref.authWithOAuthPopup` is an asynchronous operation and when it is complete it calls the provided handler. Thus `authData` exists only in the scope of this function

```
    ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function (error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else {
            var myname = authData.facebook.displayName;
            var userName;
            console.log("hi" + " " + myname);
            console.log(authData);
            $scope.userName = authData.facebook.displayName;
        }
    });
```